# Select a date in a plot with R

Tags: r, plot, statistics, selection, date-format

I'm a beginner with R and I need your help.
I plot a concentration (y) and dates (x). for about a year.
Now I want to mark a few points in red inside this plot. I know I do it with the function points. But I have difficulties with the date. For example: I want to mark the date: March the 13th 2013. I tried a few things but I have no clue, why it always returns an error...What am I doing wrong? (The time format should be European, so don't be confused about: dd/mm/yyyy)

```
win.graph(8,5)
plot(datei2$dtm, datei2$conc, xaxt="n", type="p", col="violetred2", ylim=c(350, 450), xlab="time (mm/yy)", ylab="CH4 [ppb]", xlim=c(tstart, tend), cex.lab=1.4, cex.axis=1.3)
axis.chron(1, format="%Y/%m", cex.axis =1.3)
date.select <­- dates(„13/03/2013”)
points(datei2$date[datei2$date == date.select], datei2$conc[datei2$date == date.select], col="red")
```

I hope you guys can help me out with that problem.
Thanks a lot!

Comment: You need to clarify this post. You are referencing undefined functions and we don't know anything about the data you are working with. Read up on posting reproducible problems

Answer (score 2):

Your example is not reproducible but here's an example using `zoo`. Since you are a beginner, consider `zoo` as an excellent option for dealing with time series. The only exception would be if you have intraday data. In this case, `xts` would be optimal.

```
#Create zoo object
x.Date <- as.Date("2013-03-07") + c(1, 3, 7, 9, 14) - 1
x <- zoo(rnorm(5), x.Date)

#Plot object
plot(x, xaxt="n")
axis.Date(1, x=index(x), format="%Y/%m", cex.axis =1.3)

#Add point
date.select  <- x[index(x)==as.Date("2013-03-13"),]
points(date.select, col="red", pch=16)

#Bonus: add text
text(index(date.select), date.select, labels = "My text", pos=3)
```

[image]